# How to use specific part of output of one method into other?

Tags: javafx

i am working on an application. example code is given below

```
   public class Main extends Application
{
    private BorderPane border;
      @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {   
        //Displaying all the functions in Scene 
        border = new BorderPane();    
        Scene scene = new Scene(border,750,500);        
        primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    

        //Fall-Tree Root Item
        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<String>("Library"); 
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>("Module");
        TreeItem<String> item1Child = new TreeItem<String>("MX");
        item1.getChildren().add(item1Child);

        TreeItem<String> item2 = new TreeItem<String>("Unite");
        TreeItem<String> item2Child1 = new TreeItem<String>("UX");
        TreeItem<String> item2Child2 = new TreeItem<String>("UY");
        item2.getChildren().addAll(item2Child1,item2Child2);        
        item2.setExpanded(true);    

        TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<String>("Translate");
        TreeItem<String> item3Child = new TreeItem<String>("TX");
        item3.getChildren().add(item3Child);

        TreeItem<String> item4 = new TreeItem<String>("Rotate");
        TreeItem<String> item4Child = new TreeItem<String>("Rx");
        item4.getChildren().add(item4Child);
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        tree.getChildren().addAll(item1,item2,item3,item4);
        TreeView<String> treeView  = new TreeView<String>(tree);

        //Making Tree Editable
        treeView.setEditable(true);
        treeView.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());

        //Assigning Leaf an Explorer View  
        VBox box1 = new VBox();
        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                if (newValue == item2Child1) {                           
                    box1.getChildren().add(getrightPane1());
                } else {
                        int i = box1.getChildren().size();                         
                        if (i > 0) {
                                    box1.getChildren().remove(0);
                                   }        
                        }
            }
        });

        // Main Branch        
        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                if (newValue == item2) {                           
                    box2.getChildren().add(getrightPane2());
                } else {
                        int i = box2.getChildren().size();                         
                        if (i > 0) {
                            box2.getChildren().remove(0);
                                   }        
                        }
            }
        });
        //Displaying all the Functions into border's center
        VBox vbox =new VBox(2);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        VBox.setVgrow(treeView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Text("Fall Tree"),treeView);      
        HBox hb = new HBox(); 
        hb.getChildren().addAll(vbox,box1,box2);        
        border.setCenter(hb);
    }   
    //Method for 1st Leaf Explorer View
    private BorderPane getrightPane1() {    

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7);
        TextField textf1 = new TextField();
        TextField textf2 = new TextField();
        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");   
        //Generating Rectangle's Height by providing Values in Output
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {  
                if(textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                    rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                    rect.setFill(null);
                    rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    root.setBottom(rect);
                }
            }
        });

        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        //Generating Rectangle's Width by providing Values in Output
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event)
            {
                if(textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0)
                {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                    rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                    rect.setFill(null);
                    rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    root.setBottom(rect);
                }
            }
        });

        //Labels for TextFields
        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
        root.setLeft(vbox);
        return root;
    }

    //Method for Branch Explorer View
    private HBox getrightPane2() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox(20);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(getrightPane1()); 
        return hbox;
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is how example code works

"If user put values in field provided in "UX" the rectangle is generated in UX. 
But this rectangle vanish when user clicks onto any other branch."

The application should work like this

"If user put values into **field in UX**, Create Rectangle in **UX** and in **Unite** Branch."

Please have a look at method getrightPane2, due to getting all children of getrightPane1, fields are shown in Unite and with that user can create rectangle but that is not right. Only Rectangle created in UX should be shown in Unite nothing else.  Please any hint would be fine.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class Main extends Application{
private BorderPane border;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Displaying all the functions in Scene
        border = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(border, 750, 500);
        primaryStage.setTitle("BorderPane");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        // Fall-Tree Root Item
        TreeItem<String> tree = new TreeItem<String>("Library");
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<String>("Module");
        TreeItem<String> item1Child = new TreeItem<String>("MX");
        item1.getChildren().add(item1Child);

        TreeItem<String> item2 = new TreeItem<String>("Unite");
        TreeItem<String> item2Child1 = new TreeItem<String>("UX");
        System.out.println();
        TreeItem<String> item2Child2 = new TreeItem<String>("UY");
        item2.getChildren().addAll(item2Child1, item2Child2);
        item2.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<String>("Translate");
        TreeItem<String> item3Child = new TreeItem<String>("TX");
        item3.getChildren().add(item3Child);

        TreeItem<String> item4 = new TreeItem<String>("Rotate");
        TreeItem<String> item4Child = new TreeItem<String>("Rx");
        item4.getChildren().add(item4Child);
        tree.setExpanded(true);
        tree.getChildren().addAll(item1, item2, item3, item4);
        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(tree);

        // Making Tree Editable
        treeView.setEditable(true);
        treeView.setCellFactory(TextFieldTreeCell.forTreeView());

        // Assigning Leaf an Explorer View
        VBox box1 = new VBox();
        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem> observable, TreeItem oldValue, TreeItem newValue) {
                if (newValue.getValue().equals(item2Child1.getValue())) {
                    box1.getChildren().add(getrightPane1());
                } else {
                    int i = box1.getChildren().size();
                    if (i > 0) {
                        box1.getChildren().remove(0);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

        // Main Branch
        VBox box2 = new VBox();
        treeView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TreeItem>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem> observable, TreeItem oldValue, TreeItem newValue) {
                if (newValue.getValue().equals(item2.getValue())) {
                    box2.getChildren().add(getrightPane2());
                } else {
                    int i = box2.getChildren().size();
                    if (i > 0) {
                        box2.getChildren().remove(0);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        // Displaying all the Functions into border's center
        VBox vbox = new VBox(2);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        VBox.setVgrow(treeView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(new Text("Fall Tree"), treeView);
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        hb.getChildren().addAll(vbox, box1, box2);
        border.setCenter(hb);
    }

    TextField textf1 = new TextField();
    TextField textf2 = new TextField();
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    // Method for 1st Leaf Explorer View
    private BorderPane getrightPane1() {

        VBox vbox = new VBox(20);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        HBox h1 = new HBox(7);
        HBox h2 = new HBox(7);

        textf1.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf1.setPromptText("Enter Height");
        // Generating Rectangle's Height by providing Values in Output
        textf1.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                    rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                    rect.setFill(null);
                    rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    root.setBottom(rect);
                }
            }
        });

        textf2.setPrefWidth(100);
        textf2.setPromptText("Enter Width");
        // Generating Rectangle's Width by providing Values in Output
        textf2.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                if (textf1.getText().length() > 0 && textf2.getText().length() > 0) {
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                    rect.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
                    rect.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
                    rect.setFill(null);
                    rect.setStroke(Color.RED);
                    root.setBottom(rect);
                }
            }
        });

        // Labels for TextFields
        h1.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Y:"), textf1);
        h2.getChildren().addAll(new Label("X:"), textf2);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(h1, h2);
        root.setLeft(vbox);
        return root;
    }

    // Method for Branch Explorer View
    private HBox getrightPane2() {
        HBox hbox = new HBox(20);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        System.out.println(textf1.getText());
        if (!textf1.getText().equals("") && !textf2.getText().equals("")) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.setHeight(Double.parseDouble(textf1.getText()));
            rectangle.setWidth(Double.parseDouble(textf2.getText()));
            rectangle.setFill(null);
            rectangle.setStroke(Color.RED);

            hbox.getChildren().addAll(rectangle);
        } else {
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION, "First fill the UX Field");
            alert.show();
        }

        return hbox;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Keyur Bhanderi This Won't change any thing, user need generated rectangle in Unite!!!

Comment: after execute program above, a rectangle is generated in UX if user put any values, i want that rectangle to be shown in UX and in Unite also.

Comment: Yes that is great but why is rectangle not shown in UX??   Rectangle should be in UX also. Thank you so much

Comment: Because your BorderPane root is local declaration inside a method,I have change code again and declare it global try now.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was great help.